# Can there be hidden ancient archives in Saudi Arabia?

Tags: ancient-greece, literature, saudi-arabia

Muslims once translated many ancient Greek texts. Could it be that much more is preserved, but not available to the international historical community? Could they be kept in mosques in Saudi Arabia, or have they been searched by westerners during the colonization of the arab world after their defeat in the first world war?

Comment: The Muslims who did the translating were mostly in Spain and Iraq (Baghdad and that area), not Arabia, which (other than its status as the location of the Islamic holy places) was kind of a backwater.

Comment: @user438 Is it known for many ancient texts (which were translated to arabic) where they were "re-discovered"?

Comment: This is a question about a hypothetical with no evidence.  I'm not sure that the science of history will answer this question, so I'm not sure that this question is in scope for H:SE

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I did specify by asking if westerners have had access to possible Saudi archives after the fall of the ottoman empire. I could rephrase it to that if you want. I've never heard of "stolen" Saudi Arabic treasures in European museums.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about hypothetical speculations.

Comment: There could be all sorts of ancient archives in Saudi Arabia; however, to me anyway, "hidden" archives" are by definition unknown to the world at large and so I don't see how this could be answered without resorting to speculation or unprovable assertions.

Comment: First of all I am surprised that this question is downvoted and even voted to close. That you do not know the answer is not a reason to downvote or close the question. I don't really know whether any "hidden archives" exist in Saudi Arabia, but let me mention that some very important documents have been found in collections closed for general public. The first example that comes to my mind is "Archimedes palimpsest", which was found in a Greek Orthodox library in Constantinople.
Another example is the Kievan letter (and many other prec

Comment: For any given location in the world there is a nonzero possibility that there is a hidden archive there.  So the answer is "yes", but that "yes" is useless for any practical purpose other than answering the question. The question is trivial because the answer is not useful to anyone, nor can it be.   Could mosques hold archives? Yes, but you'd be better served asking the mosques than H:SE. I'm not trying to be hostile, I just don't understand what you are asking or what the answer would mean.

Comment: Agree with the vote to close. Can there be hidden ancient archives in SA? yes, there can be. Could it be there much more is preserved ... but not...? yes, it could be. Have they been searched by "westerners"...? no. Because if these hypothetical hidden archives had been searched, it's very unlikely they, or 100% of their contents, would have remained hidden. Now, what have these answers given you?

Comment: @LocalFluff: generally they would have been rediscovered in areas that previously had been part of the Hellenistic culture area: much of the Fertile Crescent, Egypt, Constantinople, etc. Arabia is outside of that.

Answer (score 5):

Well I can't possibly find *hidden* archives using Google but there are ancient archives. And hopefully [this](http://www.al-monitor.com/pulse/culture/2014/12/saudi-arabia-archives-ancient-manuscripts-historical-texts.html) would be a relief to you in some way. And I'm community wiki-ing this answer as this is only a partial answer right now.